# Custom Navigation bar hiding tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, navbar

I have a custom navbar on a uitableviewcontroller that hides the table view.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

UINavigationBar *myBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
CGRect navBarFrame = myBar.frame;
navBarFrame.size.height = 64;
navBarFrame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
myBar.frame = navBarFrame;
[self.view addSubview:myBar];

}
```

When i try to remedy this by making the navbar not translucent:

```
myBar.translucent = NO;
```

the tableview doesnt automatically shift down, and when i try to offset the tableview:

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64,0,0,0)];
```

it offsets the navbar as well since it is a subview of the uitableview.

How do i fix this?

Also im doing this without storyboards.

Comment: Why are you adding the navigation bar as a subview of your current view? I think you should probably read up on using navigation controllers... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Im not using a navigation controller just the bar

Comment: Should i use a custom toolbar instead?

Comment: It all depends on what your goal is. If the goal is to host action buttons, a toolbar might be better suited, but there's not enough info here about why/what result you want to help make that sort of recommendation.

Comment: Well this top bar is going on a childviewcontroller for a paged view control. It may have an action button later.  basically think of snapchat and the top bars they have.  What would you believe those to be?

Comment: Looks like a nav bar to me, but it also seems like it's being used with a navController. The nav controller can have a view with a paged view control in it, so I'm still confused about your approach. Not that it's inherently or obviously wrong, but simply that on first glance you may be getting creative about how you make your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines of code in your viewDidLoad() method.

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
```